# Кастомный синтаксис post-css

Tags: javascript, postcss

Прошу помощи в решении задачи.
При написании плагина post-css хотелось бы ввести несколько ключевых слов в правила css, например:

```
.selector {
  customProperty;
  // other property....
}
```

где `customProperty` - ключевое слово, обнаружив которое pos-css поймет что это не ошибка и пометит его как `decl`, со значением `decl.value = ''`

На данный момент при записи приведенной выше получаю ошибку  `Unknown word`.
Если же записать подобным образом:

```
.selector {
      customProperty:;
      // other property....
    }
```

Т.е. ставить после свойства двоеточие то анаизатор распознает его как `decl`, но это не очень красивая запись на мой взгляд и хотелось бы её избежать оставив только ключевое слово и точку с запятой после него.
Из документации стало понятно что нужно производить манипуляции с токенайзером и парсером, но не пойму что и как необходимо сделать.